# Asymmetric torque recommendation for bottom nut on damper side vs air side on a RockShox fork

Tags: fork, suspension

I was doing lower leg service on my Recon Race solo air fork for the first time. According to the user manual from 2009 that came with the fork, bottom bolt (damper side) should be tightened with 6.8 Nm, whereas the bottom nut (air side) with only 5.1 Nm.

I had tightened the nuts to ca. 6.5 Nm and 5.0 Nm, respectively, but the air side nut was leaking oil afterwards (despite a new crush washer). Then I tightened the air side nut to ca 6.5 Nm (just like the damper side bolt) and the leak was gone. I am only worried that by solving one problem I might have created another one that will manifest itself later.

Is there a reason for this asymmetry in recommended torques for the bottom nuts in RockShox forks (Fox doesn't seem to differentiate between air/damper side bottom nut torque)? Have I done damage to my fork by tightening the air side nut to the same torque as the damper side bolt?